# Posicionar uma div no meio da tela

Tags: html, css, div

Estou com um problema pra posicionar uma `div`.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGuYn.png

Eu quero que ela continue alinhada à esquerda porém que fique centralizada no eixo Y apenas.
Tentei utilizar o transform: translate mas sem sucesso, é algo que ainda não entendo muito bem a forma de utilizar. Agradeço a atenção.

O código que to usando, to fazendo alguns testes com relação a posicionamento e ele tá bem cru ainda, questões de estilização vou me preocupar mais pra frente quando conseguir deixar tudo alinhado e responsivo:

```
"/* INICIO DO CONTAINERLEFT */

.containerleft{
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}

h3{
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
}

.selicdad{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.selicimg{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 70%;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

/* FIM DO CONTAINERLEFT */
"
```

Answer (score -3):

Tente colocar no `css` ou próprio no index caso seja a única coisa que queira fazer ali:
(exemplo no `css`)

```
div {
   text-align: center;
}
```

(exemplo interno index)

-dentro da area head-

```
<style>

div {
   text-align: center;
}

</style>
```

Caso sua `div` haja uma `class` nela, especifique-a no `css`, ou internamente no `index`

Comment: nao sei pq ali nao escreveu, mas na area head, coloque a div {text-align: center;} dentro de style

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Para centralizar a `div`, use:

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).